# booted lubuntu 14.04, canot install because installation window is empty or transparent

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, lubuntu, transparency

I booted Lubuntu 14.04 from a live CD on my old G5 PowerPC. All system windows I try to open are kind of transparent and when I move them, they drag the background with them.
So I cannot install Lubuntu, because the installation window has the same problem.

What do I do

Firefox for example will open without transparency or whatever it is, I am on Lubuntu right now...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Lubuntu 14.04 is having some display issues and not working right... if you installed it now you'd probably still have the same problems. You should probably fix the display issues first (could try booting with some of the troubleshooting-type kernel options from the grub (Ubuntu) menu, under "F6 Other Options" like nomodeset, noapic, acpi=off, etc? Often one or a combination of them get things going on older or odd hardware.

Or you could try a different desktop environment (easier).

You could try a newer Lubuntu like 14.10, or try Xubuntu, regular Ubuntu (unity or gnome3). Or even a Ubuntu-based one like Mint, it's Mate version is based off the older gnome2 and is a little "lighter" than unity/gnome3.

Just grab the .iso file and use like before. If you have a -RW disk to use that would be more economical, or a usb drive but sometimes writing a bootable live usb is even more trouble (http://www.pendrivelinux.com has been good, especially used from windows)